# Xcode 6 cannot build iCloud project

Tags: ios, xcode, icloud, code-signing-entitlements

I can't even build my project at the moment because the entitlements are wrong apparently

"None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified capabilities: Features: iCloud. iCloud containers:"

I have changed the App ID iCloud capability to use Xcode 5 compatible, but it reverts back to CloudKit on its own.

Anyone happen to have experienced and resolved this fun little trap already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing these settings has solved it. Even though the container identifier was correct, I expect it is because CloudKit is using the custom location whereas "Use default container" must be what it was before in Xcode 5 / iOS 7

[image: iCloud settings]

Comment: That's it!! I was using CloudKit with "custom containers", selecting "default container" solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by setting the provisioning profile manually, it was set to 'Automatic'

[image]